# Docker - Can't access MySQL CLI in container

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, fig

In my MySQL container that I have configured per the [official image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), it does not allow me to access the CLI from my host machine, nor any other of my containers, despite being linked:

[image: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.3']

Now, I know that I have not configured external access on my MySQL container, but how can I configure it if I can't even access the CLI to grant myself permissions? Could I create a `Dockerfile` and change some system settings before the initial installation of MySQL? If so, how would I go about doing that?

My `fig.yml` file, which is used to set up my MySQL container:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - .:/mydir
  working_dir: /mydir
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your screenshot.  (using password: NO).    Add a -p to your mysql command line.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set the environment variable `MYSQL_PWD` with the password for root. It's the official environment variable for the client.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-security-user.html